# Recursively prepend text to file names

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I want to prepend text to the name of every file of a certain type - in this case .txt files - located in the current directory or a sub-directory.

I have tried:

```
find -L . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec mv "{}" "PrependedTextHere{}" \;
```

The problem with this is dealing with the `./` part of the path that comes with the `{}` reference.

Any help or alternative approaches appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
find -L . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec bash -c 'echo "$0" "${0%/*}/PrependedTextHere${0##*/}"' {} \;
```

Where

- `bash -c '...'` executes the command
- `$0` is the first argument passed in, in this case `{}` -- the full filename
- `${0%/*}` removes everything including and after the last `/` in the filename
- `${0##*/}` removes everything before and including the last `/` in the filename

Replace the [echo](/questions/tagged/echo) with a [mv](/questions/tagged/mv) once you're satisfied it's working.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! One question: what is the `{}` at the end of the line doing exactly?

Comment: @user3477312 It's just a symbol that's used by the `find` command as a placeholder for whatever the current filename being processed is. Putting it at at the end of the exec just passes it as an argument to the command being executed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to move the files to a new file name that has `Prepend` before it?

```
for F in *.txt; do mv "$F" Prepend"$F"; done
```

Or do you want it to handle subdirectories and prepend between the directory and file name:

```
dir1/PrependA.txt
dir2/PrependB.txt
```

Comment: I would like to handle such files in all subdirectories.

Comment: I see. I would suggest something like @BroSlow's solution then, but maybe with `basename` and `dirname` to get the folder and file.

Comment: Best to put quotes around 'Prepend' such that a space can be added after Prepend - for F in *.txt; do mv "$F" 'Prepend '"$F"; done.  This is a handy tool, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @brett. That would work too, although I try to avoid spaces in file names. Maybe `Prepend_"$F"` or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick shot at it. Let me know if it helps.

```
for file in $(find -L . -type f -name "*.txt")
do
parent=$(echo $file | sed "s=\(.*/\).*=\1=")
name=$(echo $file | sed "s=.*/\(.*\)=\1=")
mv "$file" "${parent}PrependedTextHere${name}"
done
```

Comment: Did you try running this before you posted? What happened?

Comment: Thanks @Johnsyweb for that. I was not correct initially. I have edited, and believe it should be better.

Comment: You should almost never do `for something in $(command)` in bash. There are too many word splitting issues that will cause the syntax to fail (e.g. files containing spaces). See [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Doing process substitution with a `while/read` loop or one of the pipeline examples they have would work better.

Comment: You are right, this will not work on files that have spaces in their name or path, maybe good little disclaimer to put here...

Comment: @BroSlow, just curious, why is it that this does not work on files with spaces?

Comment: The internal field separator (IFS) in bash is generally set to something like `$'\t\n '` (whitespace), which means that bash will assume that a space delimits tokens, so it will split filenames with spaces into separate tokens to loop over rather than one filename.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work, as long file names does not have new line character(s). In such case make the find to use -print0 and IFS to have null.

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS='
'
for I in $(find -L . -name '*.txt' -print); do
    echo mv "$I" "${I%/*}/prepend-${I##*/}"
done
```

p.s. Remove the echo to make the script effective, it's there to avoid accidental breakage for people who randomly copy paste stuff from here to their shell.